# how to get the signed document and response after signing in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

So i am using `docusign` and testing the `api` with a simple index.php type project and i have successfully sent the document to the email provided in the 
`$signerEmail = 'test@test.com'` using `docusign api-client`

now after it have signed the document and finish it by clicking at the finish button in docusign window. I want to retrieve the response and document on which it have given its information. 
how can i achieve this and right now i am  having difficulty to find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do that, synchronously and asynchronously.
Or in other words, if you know the document is already complete, you can run the code, or you can use a webhook with notifications from DocuSign letting you know that the envelope is complete.
Regardless, the API to retrieve a document is this:

```
GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}
```

or you can use it from the PHP SDK as well.

Hope this helps.
A full code example (in PHP as well) can be found here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-download-envelope-documents

Comment: i am using PHP SDK so i have to use webhook. actually i want to triggern an event whenever response came from docusign so i am checking manually. Second thing is what is `Connect` API i mean can we use this for the same task?

Comment: connect is the name DocuSign gives their web hook mechanism. Read about it here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Connect/ConnectConfigurations/create

Comment: but i have seen connect is the other mechanism and web hook is other. In documentation both are written separately and you have to purchase connect separately.

Comment: if you are using the Developer Sandbox - you have connect in there. It is also part of almost every paid plan in production.